# D3 Placeholder for bar graph

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, placeholder

I am using the D3.js library. Version 3 *https://d3js.org/*

I have made a horizontal bar chart using data from a Json api, it works lovely.

Problem: I need to insert some text such as "No Data to Display" as a placeholder before the graph loads.


I have tried vanilla Javascript as well as creating a canvas for the place holder but neither has been successful. When implementing either, the graph will no longer load when data is added.

I am **hoping** there is an attribute or style tag I can use for this.

For example:

```
    .attr("placeholder","No Data to Display");
```

But I am looking for new ideas.

PLEASE HELP! AH!

Comment: When you say *"before the graph loads"* do you mean *"before the JSON file is downloaded and parsed"*?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado    yes

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments, it seems that you have a big JSON to download and parse and, during that time, you want to show the user that there is no data to display (yet).

You can do this using an `"progress"` event listener on your request (the `d3.json` function). In that case, something like this:

```
d3.json("foo.json")
    .on("progress", function(){
        //show user that the data is downloading
    })
    .get(callback);
```

Here is a demo, I'm downloading a huge JSON from [data.gov](https://www.data.gov/). While the JSON is being downloaded, there is a "Downloading file..." message on the screen, which is changed for "File downloaded successfully" when, well, the file is downloaded. Check it:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 50)
  .attr("y", 50)
  .style("font-size", "20px");

d3.json("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/5b3a-rs48/rows.json")
  .on("progress", function(evt) {
    text.text("Downloading file...")
  })
  .get(function(error, data) {
    text.text("File downloaded successfully")
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Ok - I guess to get more specific;  what if the json file is empty? something like     .on("empty", function(evt){ text.text("No data is on file..") is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: For example - we are downloading this json file for the graph, BUT it is empty, and we need a display message

Comment: Then display the message in the callback.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not doing what I need.

Comment: In that case, I advise you to edit your question clarifying exactly *what you need*.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I do believe I specified it. I need a place holder.

Comment: Still unclear. I rolled back the question, hope someone else can help you.

Comment: "I need to insert some text as a place holder when the graph loads" seems pretty clear. It's just what you suggested did not work. Thank you though.